# Improving heavy layout's loading time

Tags: performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android

I have an app which has quite a lot of activities, and all of the activities' layout have lots of views (TextViews, to display different kind of data in different styles, ImageViews etc).

When the activities load, they take too much time to load the layout/UI (more than a second).

**Ques:** Is there a way to reduce the time it takes to load the activity, because the activity takes too long to load the UI?

A short description of what I have:

- All the layouts have at least 30-35 views
- I am using Relative Layout
- I am not nesting layouts, most of the views are parallel to each other, and the overdraw is at max 2x
- All of the text views are custom, setting a custom font for them
- The UI is being loaded in `onCreate()` of the activity

I am thinking of doing either of the following things:

- Converting the app into Fragments in a way there are less number of activities, and more number of fragments. For example, there is one Home Activity which loads the first fragment, and further interactions with the app keep loading/switching between fragments for different purposes via Fragment Transactions. I would spawn a new activity only when I am hitting a limitation of Fragments.
  Will it help improve the speed?
- Disintegrate the UI in a way were the most basic UI is loaded in the view once the activity starts, and all the other UI elements are `inflated` in a background thread (AsyncTask) and are then `added` to the root of the current view.

In different opinions, which approach would be better?
Is there a better or standard way of solving this problem?

Appreciating all the inputs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about ViewStub? with stubs your initial loading time would be shorter

Comment: Seeing `ViewStub` now, wondering if it can be invoked in a background thread and once done the UI can be updated... I think it can't be done..

Comment: try to use ListView with diifernt item view ....

Comment: @SheikhAman you can inflate ViewStubs in UI thread one be one

Comment: @Haresh : I am not representing data which is vertically scrollable, thus ListView doesn't make sense. That say, wherever necessary, I am using ListView already

Comment: We don't have the code of your activities nor the layouts, so we could simply guess. Any network operation? Databases? Bitmaps? Huge images as background? There are several causes but without your code we cannot help you at 100%.

Comment: @fasteque Sorry, but the situation is simple. I've spent time on finding that its actually the loading of UI which is taking time. I am not doing any of the heavy running on the UI thread, everything like fetching data from web and local database is being done in a background thread. Only setting the views and their properties (margins, positions, backgrounds etc) is taking time.

Comment: Yes, but at least post one layout for a view, so we can help you. Otherwise profile your UI with the Hierarchy Viewer as explained here: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some more suggestions to what you've already going to do.

1. If you inject views in `onCreate()` method, make sure you use design-time injection frameworks (Bufferknife or AndroidAnnotations) and not runtime ones (Guice, RoboGuice). Runtime frameworks definitely slow startup time down.
2. If you have views, which are not visible to the user initially, you can use [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) and load them on demand.

Comment: I am not using any of those injection mechanisms, I am just using plain `setContentView(int resId)` inside `onCreate()`. Do you think using any of those injection frameworks will be helpful?  Seeing ViewStub now

Comment: Then I am already not using them, shouldn't make any difference, right?

Comment: @beworker Which one is better - doing some work in onCreateView() or onActivityCreated()?

Comment: @zIronManBox better for what?

Comment: @beworker in terms of performance, doing complex task `onCreateView()` or `onActivityCreated()`?

Comment: @zIronManBox if you want UI to be responsive all the time you should perform no complex tasks in either of those methods because they are executed in main thread. Use AsyncTask or background thread for this. You can also read this: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: @beworker Now how do you know that task are complex? What is its just loading a class or Mapview loading tiles or similar?